# How to write a query for listing of related models

Tags: laravel-lighthouse

I have a eloquent model and graphql type `First`.
I have a eloquent model and graphql type `Second`.
They have a `belongsToMany` relationship between them, `firsts` and `seconds`.

I want to write a query where given a `id` for `First` model, I should be able to return a listing of its `seconds` relationship.

Currently I'm achieving this by doing this.
query

```
firstSeconds(id: ID!): [Second!]! @paginate(scopes: ["secondsByFirstId"])
```

Second Model

```
    public function scopeSecondsByFirstId($query, $args)
    {
        if (empty($args['id'])) {
            return $query;
        }

        $firstId = $args['id'];
        $first = First::find($firstId);
        $secondIds = $first->seconds()
            ->get()
            ->pluck('id');

        return $query->whereIn('id', $secondIds);
    }
```

Note: `return $first->seconds()` didn't work for me but that is a laravel thing.

I want to know if there is a way to achieve this without using a scope and using basic relationship directives.

Note: I want only the paginated list of `Second` model. NOT instance of `First` model with paginated `seconds` relationship attached.